# Is there a module in Linux Kernel for copying data directly between two character devices in kernel space?

Tags: linux, module, serial-port, kernel, multiplexing

We need to multiplex data from one (USB) serial device to multiple independent serial devices.
What I've found, is the module [fanout](http://linuxgazette.net/122/smith.html), this addresses the multiplexing part of my problem.

Now I search for an easy, probably ready to use, way to copy the data from the serial USB device to the **fanout** device directly in the kernel space.
Sure, I'am able to simply `cat x > y` in userspace, but It may be more efficient to do this in kernel space.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [anonymous Unix Domain Socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket), created with **socketpair**.  Satisfies all your conditions (and is fast).

Answer (score 0):

If you can have a pipe, try [`splice_pipe_to_pipe`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6.2/fs/splice.c#L1802) or `link_pipe`.

(btw, the new [`tee` syscall](http://lwn.net/Articles/118750/) can replace fanout module. and it's buildin already!)